# Image uploading from Angular 4 to ASP.NET Api getting 401

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-web-api

I have an API built on asp.net. I am trying to upload an image via this API but getting 401 response. Same API is working in postman.
I using Auth0, so using token but token is not the issue because I tried using Postman token in my angular web app and web token in the postman and in both cases postman works but the web is not.
Also it is not the issue with allowing origin URL because all other API's are working.
Fiddler response I am uploading image via Postman

> Request Header

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------930238038400236037556404
Authorization: bearer {token}
cache-control: no-cache
Postman-Token: e0914722-51ae-46ae-89e1-374083db2e7e
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.1.1
Accept: */*
Host: Azurowebsite
cookie: ARRAffinity=85c14af7254dbffe56e4b0a1bcfc7587606ee9c95b1b694237067a43fe554677
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
content-length: 90000
Connection: keep-alive
```

> Response Header

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
ETag: "46008695-0000-0000-0000-5a714d080000"
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: Kestrel
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 31 Jan 2018 04:58:47 GMT
X-Cache: MISS from gateway
X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from gateway
Via: 1.0 gateway.purelogics.net (squid/3.1.23)
Connection: close
Content-Length: 1570
```

And from web the fiddler response is

> Request Header

```
Host: azurowebsite
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 89976
Accept: Bearer {token}
Origin: testing server
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json
Referer: testing server
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
```

> Response Header

```
HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized
Server: Kestrel
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: Testing server
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Set-Cookie: ARRAffinity=85c14af7254dbffe56e4b0a1bcfc7587606ee9c95b1b694237067a43fe554677;Path=/;HttpOnly;Domain=zytoproductxwebapi-testing.azurewebsites.net
Date: Wed, 31 Jan 2018 04:59:04 GMT
Content-Length: 0
X-Cache: MISS from gateway
X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from gateway
Via: 1.0 gateway.purelogics.net (squid/3.1.23)
Connection: keep-alive
```

Comment: what is the content type you are setting in the web versiion

Comment: I have tried both Content-Type: application/json and multipart/form-data

Comment: you are using web API right?

Comment: Yes but API is built on ASP.NET

Answer (score -1):

**Solved**. In case anyone faces this issue.
The problem was not in the API nor in the code. Problem was that this ngx-uploader package does not allow sending token in the header section. I know its strange, package author should allow this.
I spent two days looking for a solution to this error. It turns out that this package only allow the token to be sent in this custom parameter

```
authToken: token
```

Instead of

```
header : {Authorization : token}
```

So my short code to call API is

```
public uploaderOptions: NgUploaderOptions = {
url: this.url,
method: 'POST',
filterExtensions: true,
allowedExtensions: ['jpg', 'png'],
authToken   : localStorage.getItem('id_token'),
```

};